# how to get minimum in 2d array java

Tags: java

I need help, please! I am building up the following code to extract the minimum value of each column of the distance

I have tried to compute the code but to no avail

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int data[] = {2, 4, -10, 12, 3, 20, 30, 11};//,25,17,23};    // initial data
    int noofclusters = 3;
    int centroid[][] = new int[][]{
            {0, 0, 0},
            {2, 4, 30}
    };
    getCentroid(data, noofclusters, centroid);
}

public static int[][] getCentroid(int[] data, int noofclusters, int[][] centroid) {

    int distance[][] = new int[noofclusters][data.length];
    int cluster[] = new int[data.length];
    int clusternodecount[] = new int[noofclusters];


    centroid[0] = centroid[1];
    centroid[1] = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
    System.out.println("========== Starting to get new centroid =========");

    for (int i = 0; i < noofclusters; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            //System.out.println(distance[i][j]+"("+i+","+j+")="+data[j]+"("+j+")-"+centroid[0][i]+"="+(data[j]-centroid[0][i]));
            distance[i][j] = Math.abs(data[j] - centroid[0][i]);
            System.out.print(distance[i][j] + " ,");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    int[] result = new int[distance.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < distance.length; i++) {
            //int min = distance;
            int min = distance[i][0];
            for (int j = 0; j < distance[0].length; j++) {

                if (distance[i][j] < min) {
                    min = distance[i][j];
                }

                result[j] = min;
                System.out.println(result[j] + ", ");
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The result of the computation for distance gives

> ```
> row 1:    0 ,2 ,12 ,10, 1 ,18 ,28 ,9 
> row 2:    2 ,0 ,14 ,8 , 1 ,16 ,26 ,7 
> row 3:   28,26,40 ,18, 27 ,10 ,0 ,19
> ```

I want to go through each column to get the minimum value

```
0 0 12 8 1 10 0 7
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: What result do you get? Can you describe in more detail what the issue is with your code? _Edit_ I forgot to mention, could you explain what it is you are trying to accomplish? What is this code supposed to do, the current explanation is hard to understand,

Comment: Obs: 1 - returning `centroid` not `result` (intentional?) 2 - the last 2 loops are mixed (assigning to `result` each iteration of inner loop) 3 - code is a bit too much just to find minimum

Comment: Hi Carlos  yes I have return result .  I do not really understand your statement 2.  Please kindly verify

Comment: From a brief look, it looks like this is down to misplacement of your curly brackets towards the end of the code

Comment: Hi Joakim  I am getting a 2d arrays for the distance. I want to find the minimum of each column.  which gives the answer 0 0 12 8 1 10 0 7

Comment: Use a debugger to check what your code is doing. Your method signature is incorrect, you mixed up `data.length` and `distance.length` for the finding of the minimum and as `@CarlosHeuberger` mentioned, your last two loops are mixed.

Comment: you actually wrote "I want to go through each column" - you must first have the column loop, then (inside) the row one: `for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
            result[j] = array[0][j];
            for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i][j] < result[j]) {
                    result[j] = array[i][j];
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: int[] result = new int[data.length];
  //for (int i = 0; i < distance.length; i++) {
  //int min = distance;
  for (int j = 0; j < distance[0].length; j++) {
   result[j] = distance[0][j];
   for (int i = 1; i < distance.length; i++) {
    if (distance[i][j] < result[j]) {

     result[j] = distance[i][j];
    }
    System.out.println(result[j] + ", ");
   }
               System.out.println();
  }
  return result;

Comment: Hi Carlos Heuberger thanks for your help, I have actually edited as explained and I am getting the following answer  0,0   0,0   12, 12    8, 8   1, 1   16 ,10  26, 0 and 7, 7        please what could be wrong.  I am getting closer.  Thanks again

Comment: is that the content of `result` or what is being printed on console? check exactly **where** you are printing, that for sure is not what is inside `result` (at the end of the loops/method)

Comment: try `System.out.println(i + "," + j + ": " + result[j]);` instead, maybe it will be clear what is going on - better, as [second](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11514534/second) already suggested, use a debugger, is always helpful

Comment: Hi Carlos : it is what I am getting in the console.  it is printing in 2's the latter number for each is the correct.  Any help in figuring this out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the minimum value in each column, first, you need to iterate the column in the outer loop. By doing so, we can access the matrix colunm-wise.

Assign the first value of each column to a variable. Then iterate through the rows in the inner loop.

Check if the current value is less than the minimum value. If so, assign the smallest value to minimum.

When we use an array, we get an array of minimum values of the column.

To obtain the minimun value in each row, swap the loops and use `min[i]`.

Below is an example code:

```
int []min = new int[column_lenght];
for(int j = 0; j < column_length; j++) {
    min[j] = array[i][j];
    for(int i = 0; i < row_length; i++) {
        if(array[i][j] < min[j]) {
            min[j] = array[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

The `min[]` will contain the minimum value of each column.